# Boostrap Datepicker - months and year only doesn't work

Tags: javascript, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm studying on how to use `bootstrap datepicker` but i need it to show only the months or year just like this:
[image]

but the result only became like this:

[image]

I only need to pick the month and the year not the whole calendar.
Below is my whole code snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker( {
        format: "mm-yyyy",
        startView: "months", 
        minViewMode: "months"
    });
})
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <title>My Teasting Website</title>

  <!--Bootstrap css-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!--bootstrap-datepicker css-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/datepicker/css/datepicker.css">

</head>

<body>


    <input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="date" id="datepicker">

  <script src="/src/jquery.js"></script>
  <!--Bootstrap js-->
  <script src="src/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/src/datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: try to write `<script src="/src/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>` instead of `<script src="src/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I added `/` in the beginning

Comment: It still didn't work after adding `/`

Comment: what version of `bootstrap-datepicker` do you use?

Comment: bootstrap 1.9.0? This is the site where i got my download. https://uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=input&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&maxViewMode=4&todayBtn=false&clearBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox

Comment: the following fiddle works with v1.9.0: http://jsfiddle.net/f7zjgyse/

Comment: @ElijahLeis, please check my new answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functionality you are looking for is in datetimepicker, not in just datepicker. It has the UI the way you want.

**Note:** The calendar will show Month or Year, but when you select a particular value, it will show it as YYYY-MM format. It is not possible to show either YYYY or MM in the textbox after selecting the value from calendar.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
    viewMode: 'months',
    format: 'YYYY-MM'
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class='input-group date'>
          <input type='text' class="form-control" id='datetimepicker2' />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: love you bro.... thanks